# Symfony2 Registration form with only single record of collection field

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

So I'm trying to create a registration form in Symfony 2 which contains my "Person" entity.  The person entity has a one-to-many join, and I want the registration form to allow the user to select a single instance of this "Many" side of the join.

The structure is `Users` and `Institutions`.  A user can have many institutions.  I want a user to select a single institution at registration time (but the model allows for more later).

The basic structure is:

> RegistrationType -> PersonType -> PersonInstitutionType

…with corresponding models:

> Registration (simple model) -> Person (doctrine entity) -> PersonInstitution (doctrine entity, oneToMany relation from Person)

I tried to pre-populate an empty `Person` & `PersonInstitution` record in the `RegistrationController` but it gives me the error:

> Expected argument of type "string or Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface", "TB\CtoBundle\Entity\PersonInstitution" given

(ok above has been fixed).

I've moved the code from my website to here below, trying to remove all the irrelevant bits.

src/TB/CtoBundle/Form/Model/Registration.php

```
namespace TB\CtoBundle\Form\Model;
use TB\CtoBundle\Entity\Person;
class Registration 
{
  /**
   * @var Person
   */
  private $person
  private $termsAccepted;
}
```

src/TB/CtoBundle/Form/RegistrationType.php

```
namespace TB\CtoBundle\Form;
use TB\CtoBundle\Form\PersonType;
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('person',  new PersonType());
        $builder->add('termsAccepted','checkbox');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'TB\CtoBundle\Form\Model\Registration',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'registration';
    }
}
```

src/TB/CtoBundle/Entity/Person.php

```
namespace TB\CtoBundle\Entity;
use TB\CtoBundle\Entity\PersonInstitution
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Person
{
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PersonInstitution", mappedBy="person", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $institutions;
}
```

src/TB/CtoBundle/Form/PersonType.php

```
namespace TB\CtoBundle\Form;
class PersonType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('institutions', 'collection', array('type' => new PersonInstitutionType()))
        ;
    }

   /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'TB\CtoBundle\Entity\Person',
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'tb_ctobundle_person';
    }
}
```

src/TB/CtoBundle/Entity/PersonInstitution.php

```
namespace TB\CtoBundle\Entity
/**
 * PersonInstitution
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class PersonInstitution
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="institutions", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $person;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Institution", inversedBy="members")
     */
    private $institution;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $approved;
}
```

src/TB/CtoBundle/Form/PersonInstititionType.php

```
namespace TB\CtoBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class PersonInstitutionType extends AbstractType
{
        /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('approved')
            ->add('person')
            ->add('institution')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'TB\CtoBundle\Entity\PersonInstitution'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'tb_ctobundle_personinstitution';
    }
}
```

src/TB/CtoBundle/Controller/Registration.php

```
namespace TB\CtoBundle\Controller;
class RegisterController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * 
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        $registration = new Registration;

        $person = new Person();
        $institution = new PersonInstitution();
        $person->addInstitution($institution);
        $registration->setPerson($person);

// this causes error:
// Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager? 
//        $institution->setPerson($person);

        $form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationType(), $registration);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isValid()) {
            $registration = $form->getData();
            $person = $registration->getPerson();

            // new registration - account status is "pending" 
            $person->setAccountStatus("P");

            // I'd like to get rid of this if possible
            // for each "PersonInstitution" record, set the 'person' value
            foreach($person->getInstitutions() as $rec) {
                $rec->setPerson($person);
            }

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($person);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->render('TBCtoBundle:Register:register.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I've added the relevant code to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a detailed solution for adding an Collection field to Person entity and formType.
Your complex question with Registration entity can be solved with this.
I suggest you to use this 3 entity related connection if it is really needed. (only because of termsAccepted data!?)

*If you won't change your opinion, then use this annotation:*
**Registration code**:

```
use TB\CtoBundle\Entity\Person;
/**
  * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Person")
  * @var Person
  */
protected $person;
```

**Person code**:

```
use TB\CtoBundle\Entity\PersonInstitution;

/**
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PersonInstitution", mappedBy = "person")
  * @var ArrayCollection
  */
private $institutions;

/* I suggest you to define these functions:
setInstitutions(ArrayCollection $institutions),
getInstitutions()
addInstitution(PersonInstitution $institution)
removeInstitution(PersonInstitution $institution)
*/
```

**PersonInstitution code**:

```
use TB\CtoBundle\Entity\Person;

/**
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="institutions", cascade={"persist"}))
  * @var Person
  */
private $person;
```

**PersonType code**:

```
use TB\CtoBundle\Form\PersonInstitutionType;

->add('institutions', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new PersonInstitutionType(), // here is your mistake!
                // Other options can be selected here.
                //'allow_add' => TRUE,
                //'allow_delete' => TRUE,
                //'prototype' => TRUE,
                //'by_reference' => FALSE,
));
```

**PersonController code**:

```
use TB\CtoBundle\Entity\Person;
use TB\CtoBundle\Entity\PersonInstitution;

/**
  * ...
  */
public funtcion newAction()
{
  $person = new Person;
  $institution = new PersonInstitution;
  $institution->setPerson($person);
  $person->addInstitution($institution);
  $form = $this->createForm(new PersonType($), $person); // you can use formFactory too.

  // If institution field is required, then you have to check,
  // that is there any institution able to chose in the form by the user.
  // Might you can redirect to institution newAction in that case.

  return array( '...' => $others, 'form' => $form);
}
```

*If you need more help in twig code, then ask for it.*

Comment: I need "Registration" to enforce accepting terms before submitting the form.  Registration is only a "model" type, but it's not an entity saved to the database.

Comment: Hm, when I do $institution->setPerson($person), I get an error 
"Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?"

When I don’t do this, the PersonInstitution database table gets a null person_id.  Digging a little further to see if I can get it on my own.

Comment: I've added the relevant code to the post.  Everything basically works now, but I'd like to remove the foreach loop if possible from the Registration controller.  The "Person" relation isn't being set because I'm only rendering the "Institution" side of the PersonInstitution on the form.  I'd hoped the OneToMany/ManyToOne would take care of this.